# Combine search from 2 rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I run a survey where all answers are stored in a separate row in the 'survey' table.
My table looks like this:

```
(ID,user_id,Q,A)
(1,10,'laundry','oxiclean')
(2,10,'laundry','tide')
(3,10,'laundry','pods')
(4,11,'laundry','spray n wash')
(5,11,'laundry','resolve')
(6,12,'laundry','oxiclean')
(7,13,'laundry','oxiclean')
```

I now need to pull the count of user id that selected ONLY specific products.

```
"SELECT *, count(user_id) FROM survey WHERE Q='laundry' GROUP BY a"
```

the above will give a an overall COUNT but I need to get my count based on users that selected ONLY 'oxiclean' for example. This should return 2.

Or users that selected 'oxiclean' AND 'tide' ONLY.

How do I go about performing this 'combination' of results pulled from different rows?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: WHERE Q='laundry' AND A='oxiclean'?  Also, there appear to be three, not two.

Comment: User id=10 has multiple answers, including 'oxiclean'. I need the users who answered 'oxiclean' and nothing else. So, there are really only 2 users who answered ONLY 'oxiclean'. What I'm looking for is how to make that ONLY selection clause. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id from survey group by user_id having count(user_id) = 1
```

This retrieves a list of users which have only one answer in the survey. Use it as a filter condition:

```
select q,a,count(user_id) 
from survey
where a = 'oxiclean'
and user_id in (select user_id from survey group by user_id having count(user_id) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html), for your case it will be something like that :

```
SELECT *, COUNT(user_id)
FROM survey AS s
WHERE Q = 'laundry'
AND A = 'oxiclean'
AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM survey WHERE Q = s.Q AND A != s.A);
```

`s.Q` and `s.A` refer to the parent field so you don't have to reinject the name a second time.
Downside : the query works only if you want one specific answer.

If you want one query to retrieve the overall count, this one should do the trick :

```
SELECT A, COUNT(user_id)
FROM (
  SELECT A, user_id
  FROM survey
  WHERE Q='laundry'
  GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 1
  ) AS t
GROUP BY A
```

Downside : the query give only answers who have only at least one unique user_id as seen [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86270/1), and this syntax create a temporary table which is something to avoid for performance reasons.